# WebClient in Java Spring replaces the '%' character when I don't want it to

Tags: java, json, spring, uri, spring-webclient

I am trying to create a URI that contains a '#'. I understand that that needs to be replaced by "%23", so I do. However, when using WebClient to connect to the endpoint, it automatically replaces the '%' with "%25", so I end up with "%2523".

I tried just leaving the '#' character in, thinking that it replaced all illegal characters with their encoded format (I may be using the wrong terms here) but it does not replace it. Below is what I have, nothing too complicated.

UPDATE: tag is a short string that contains a '#' character with every other character being valid. In the below example, tag is `#8QQRVVL0`. It is not a URI fragment, just the way the identifier system was designed.

```
if(tag.contains("#")){
            tag = tag.replace("#", "%23");
        }
        UserStatistics user = new UserStatistics();
        String playersEndpoint = "players/";
        JSONObject json = webClient.get()
                .uri(playersEndpoint + tag)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(JSONObject.class)
                .block();
```

The rest of my URI is created when I instantiate the WebClient object, prior in the Class.

Comment: would you mind pasting where tag is defined?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: @Jens What other context is necessary?

Comment: Is your tag supposed to be a URI fragment?

Comment: No, frustratingly enough it's just part of the player identifier. There is also no other way to look up a player's info (no numerical ID or something), so I have to end the URI with `.../players/%238QQRVVL0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
String url = "https://example.com?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(q, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The reason this is happening is because Java spring uses what is known as percent encoding - that's why % is being converted to a %25, more on this here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

If you can give some more details about where & how you've defined tag, I may be able to give other specific suggestions.

Update:
Maybe you could try something like this?

```
JSONObject json = webClient.get()
            .uri(playersEndpoint + UriUtils.encodePath(tag, "UTF-8")))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(JSONObject.class)
            .block();
```

Follow up update:

Try updating the / inside of playersEndpoint with %2F instead?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I've updated the question to reflect the value of tag. I'm not trying to create a query within the URI, I'm trying to use GET to retrieve information that is tied to a specific player (denoted by their tag). The end URI should look like this:

.../players/%238QQRVVL0

Comment: You're welcome!
I'll update my comment with some new code, but I think you still might be able to use something like this

Comment: Let me know if encoding the path when you call the GET works! Note that depending on your server, you may need UTF-16

Comment: Hmm, I thought that would work but unfortunately it didn't. It did change my result though, now instead of `%25238QQRVVL0` I get `%2525238QQRVVL0` in my URI.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I tried both UTF-8 and UTF-16, UTF-16 gives a much larger URI

Comment: What if you try removing the replace but keeping the encoder? does it then encode properly?

Comment: Weirdly enough it still does the double replace! `/players/%25238QQRVVL0` is the URI. This is exactly why I'm stumped, it seems to only be replacing the '%' character and nothing else, even when the '%' character is totally valid.

Comment: AH I SEE it! it could be the slash
The slash is probably causing you these issues

Comment: Can you try updating the / inside of playersEndpoint with %2F instead?
https://seonorth.ca/server/forward-slash-in-url/#:~:text=In%20URLs%2C%20special%20characters%20like,character%20is%20encoded%20as%20%2F%20.

Comment: Shoot I would love to move this to chat but I don't have enough reputation lol. The slash does need to be in there, and as far as I'm aware shouldn't cause any problems affecting other characters.

AH just saw your other message, let me try.

Comment: That just made it encode the other percent sign as `%252F`, compounding the problem :(

Comment: What was the resolution finally ?